# C++ initializing the dynamic array elements

Tags: c++

```
const size_t size = 5;
int *i = new int[size]();

for (int* k = i; k != i + size; ++k)                                            

{                                                                               
 cout << *k <<  endl;                                         

}
```

Even though I have value initialized the dynamic array elements by using the () operator, the output I get is

```
135368
0
0
0
0
```

Not sure why the first array element is initialized to 135368.

Any thoughts ?

Comment: I think this is a compiler bug. Some compilers seem to have problems with value initialization: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/utility/value_init.htm

Comment: Is value initialization on an array using `new []` even well-formed? I cannot find anything in the standard suggesting that it does (looking at §5.3.4).

Comment: A `new-type-id` cannot be a function-type syntactically. That way, `T[N]()` is not an array of functions, but rather an array value-initialized (so `5.3.4/15` applies).

Comment: 5.3.4/15: If the new-initializer is of the form (), the item is value-initialized (8.5)

Comment: Incorrect handling of '()' initializer was rather widespread in older compilers. In your case it appears to be a compiler bug.

Comment: @captonssj - what compiler & compiler version are you using?

Comment: I tried it on GCC 3.4.5 when I got home, and it definitely isn't initializing the array as it should.  As litb's Boost link points out, apparently this is a very common compiler bug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My first thought is: "**NO**...just say **NO**!"

Do you have some really, truly, unbelievably good reason not to use vector?

```
 std::vector<int> i(5, 0);
```

Edit: Of course, if you want it initialized to zeros, that'll happen by default...

Edit2: As mentioned, what you're asking for is value initialization -- but value initialization was added in C++ 2003, and probably doesn't work quite right with some compilers, especially older ones.

Comment: I am not trying to make a choice between Vectors and Arrays.  I am playing around with arrays and see how they behave.  Learning process for a C++ course I am taking :)

Answer (score 3):

I agree with litb's comment. It would appear to be a compiler bug.

Putting your code in a `main` function and prefixing with:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::size_t;
```

I got five zeros with both gcc 4.1.2 and a gcc 4.4.0 on a linux variant.

**Edit:**

Just because it's slightly unusual with array type: In a new expression an initializer of `()` means that the dynamically allocated object(s) are *value initialized*. This is perfectly legal even with array `new[...]` expressions. It's not valid to have anything other than a pair of empty parentheses as an initializer for an array `new` expression, although non-empty initializers are common for for non-array `new` epxressions.

Comment: And with MinGW GCC 3.4.5 I get 5 garbage numbers.